# How to set up 2D pose with IMU and odometry using robot localization ekf?

Tags: robotics, ros2

I have a differential drive robot, it is a 4wd robot, 2 motors, 2 encoders,s it behaves like a differential robot actually. Odometry from encoders is working well. I'm using ROS2 Humble on ubuntu 22.04.

I want to fuse odom, with an IMU to get a nice 2d pose (lokalisation)

So, I have done all the transform and got the odom and IMU topics. Which are the followings
ODOM topic:

> header:   stamp:
> sec: 1708934625
> nanosec: 68893329   frame_id: odom child_frame_id: laser_link pose:   pose:
> position:
> x: 0.9908038973808289
> y: -3.18342661857605
> z: 0.0
> orientation:
> x: 0.0
> y: 0.0
> z: 0.808424464005272
> w: 0.5885999371370919   covariance:
>
> - 8.632683822477702e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 8.632683822477702e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 8.632683822477702e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 8.632683822477702e-06
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 8.632683822477702e-06
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 8.632683822477702e-06 twist:   twist:
>   linear:
>   x: 0.05744318664073944
>   y: -0.010725230909883976
>   z: 0.0
>   angular:
>   x: 0.0
>   y: -0.0
>   z: 0.046282440423965454   covariance:
> - 4.316341911238851e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 4.316341911238851e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 4.316341911238851e-05
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 4.316341911238851e-06
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 4.316341911238851e-06
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 4.316341911238851e-06

AND IMU topic

> header:   stamp:
> sec: 1708934700
> nanosec: 58079488   frame_id: camera_imu_optical_frame orientation:   x: -0.564959732796857   y: -0.32758730601200314   z:
> 0.3634408670297931   w: 0.664392800555917 orientation_covariance:
>
> - 0.0004
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0004
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0004 angular_velocity:   x: 0.0   y: -0.006981316953897476   z: 0.0 angular_velocity_covariance:
> - 0.01
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.01
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.01 linear_acceleration:   x: 0.22555294632911682   y: -9.728196144104004   z: 1.4808040857315063 linear_acceleration_covariance:
> - 1.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 1.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 0.0
> - 1.0
>
> ---

So Im not sure about the correct EKF yamil config file.

My suggestion was this config

> ```
>     odom0: /odom/icp
>     odom0_config: [true, true, true,  # pose position (x, y, z)
>            true, true, true, true,  # pose orientation (quaternion x, y, z, w)
>            false, false, false, false, false, false,  # pose covariance
>            true, true, false]
>
>     imu0: /imu/data
>     imu0_config: [false, false, false,
>                   true,  true,  false,
>                   false, false, false,
>                   false, true, false,
>                   true, true, false]
> ```

But not sure if the correct one. Any help?